# How to get a position of specific node

Tags: xslt

There is a XML structure:

```
<school>
    <class>
        <student>
            <ID>0023</ID>
            <NAME>JOHN</NAME>
        </student>
        <student>
            <ID>0067</ID>
            <NAME>STEVE</NAME>
        </student> 
        <student>
            <ID>0094</ID>
            <NAME>MARY</NAME>
        </student> 
        <student>
            <ID>0108</ID>
            <NAME>SARA</NAME>
        </student> 
        <student>
            <ID>0234</ID>
            <NAME>MARTIN</NAME>
        </student> 
    </class>
</school>
```

I need to get a position of specific node. If I ask for Steve then I receive 2 as a result. Because this is a second student from my list (sort by ID).

```
<steve_seq> 2 </steve_seq>
```

Thanks in advance.

I've tried this:

```
 <steve_seq> 
<xsl:value-of select="count(school/class/student/name[.='steve']/preceding-sibling::name)+1"/> 
</steve_seq>
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. We expect people to put effort in before asking, otherwise you're asking us to do the work without any evidence that you've tried to do this yourself. Please **edit** your question with your code, and expected outputs. You're also asking two distinct questions, when really it should only be a single question for people to answer. Please have a read of the [help] and the [ask] section in particular.

Comment: It's not clear how you "ask for Steve". In general, you can count preceding siblings or - in XSLT 2.0 - use the `index-of` function.

Comment: Can you give me an example how would you do that?

Comment: I tried:  <sch:Test>   <xsl:value-of select="count(school/class/student/name[.='steve']/preceding-sibling::name)+1"/> </sch:Test>  -  dosn't work. What's wrong?

Comment: How would I do what? I gave you two options. And you did not answer my question.

Comment: P.S. Please don't post code in comments - edit your question instead.

Comment: I want to use XSLT to receive an answer. I already find out count preceding siblings but I dont know how to use it in my example ? Sorry I'm very beginner.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to hard-code the name into your stylesheet, you could do:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <steve_seq>
        <xsl:value-of select="count(school/class/student[NAME='STEVE']/preceding-sibling::student) + 1"/> 
    </steve_seq>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

Note that XSLT is case sensitive: `name` is not the same thing as `NAME` and `'steve'` is not the same as `'STEVE'`.